# Connect to SQL Server 2012 with server form error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

Why this connecting is error.

in form server button_click in btnconnect

```
ClassConnection.server = txtservername.Text;// servername is @.\\SQLEXPRESS
ClassConnection.data = txtdatabase.Text;// database is @db_computer
ClassConnection.user = txtusername.Text;// username is @admin
ClassConnection.code = txtpassword.Text;//password is @123

new frm_login().Show();
this.Hide();
```

Code in ClassConnection

```
public static class ClassConnection
{
    public static string server, data, user, code;
    public static string conn = "server="+server+"; database="+data+"; user="+user+"; password="+code+"; Integrated Security=True";

    public static DataTable getdata(string sql, string tbname)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, new SqlConnection(conn));
        da.Fill(ds, tbname);
        dt = ds.Tables[tbname];
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Btnlogin click to login to form_main

```
if (txtloginpassword.Text == "" && txtloginname.Text=="")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fill Username and password");
    return;
}
else
{
    string selectuser = "select Username, Userpassword from tb_user         where Username=N'" + txtloginname.Text + "' and Userpassword=N'" + txtloginpassword.Text + "'";

    DataTable dt = ClassConnection.getdata(selectuser, "tbname");

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        new Test.frm_main().Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("not found username and password");
        return;
    }
}
```

This logging in give the error like the image attachment:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f51Pi.png)

Why is it wrong? and how?

if I debug without server form the connection string would be like

```
public static string conn = "server=.\\SQLEXPRESS; database=db_computer; user=admin; password=123; Integrated Security=True";
```

it is working as well.

Comment: You got an error saying the server doesn't exist and you're asking us what could be happening?  How would we know?

Comment: Just a hunch: make sure that you set `txtservername.Text` to contain **1 backslash** and not two. Doubling the backslash is only needed to create the c# string literal (a technique called *escaping*).

Comment: *hint* when ( at what point) do you think`ClassConnection.conn` 's value is set (when does the initializer run and are the girls it depends on also initialized with the expected values at that point)

Comment: Because your connection string looks like this: `server=; database=; user=; password=; Integrated Security=True`.  That conn string won't magically update itself.